# Error testing Webview component using Espresso on Android

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to test some values of a webview component using Espresso.
Here is the chart's
[android hierarchy inspector image](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=516476AndroidInspector.png).

And here is the chart's [HTML inspector image](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=141547HTMLInspector.png).

I'm trying to access the grid using this code snippet:
`onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.CLASS_NAME, "concept-5089"));`
Considering that there is a row whose class element contains *concept-5089*.

But when i try to execute this code, the application stops to response.

What am i missing ? If more information is need, please, let me know so that i can post it here

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry for an offtopic, but what is the name of the tool that shows Android views hierarchy in a DevTools-like manner (the first screenshot)?

Comment: It is chrome://inspect, @MikhailNaganov

Comment: Ah, it must be DevTools + Stetho (http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) actually. Neat.

Comment: yeap, @MikhailNaganov. I forgot about Stetho, but that's exactly that ..

Comment: @MikhailNaganov you can also run uiautomatorviewer on terminal